# Flutter : How save data comes from database (Future) in a list in provider

Tags: flutter, future, provider

I have a service where I am receiving some data from API :

```
import '../models/clubs.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiService {
  var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/v1/';

  getActiveSeasonClubs() async {
    var newurl = Uri.parse(url + 'active_season_clubs/');
    var response = await http.get(newurl);
    var data = clubsFromJson((response.body));
    return data;
  }
}
```

I want to make a copy of this list of data in provider to use it and update it in the app ,I used this but null data recieved :

```
class TeamsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  var _clubs = [];
  get clubs => loadValue();
  Future loadValue() async {
    _clubs = await ApiService().getActiveSeasonClubs();
    return _clubs;
  }
}
```

and used it in FutureBuilder :

```
body: Consumer<TeamsProvider>(builder: (context, teamsProv, child) {
          return FutureBuilder(
              future: teamsProv.clubs,
```

Comment: I think you need call the function on the future: teamsProv.loadValue(),

Comment: @JorgeVieira it get data in future builder ,but i want to save it in list to make update on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make these modifications:

```
class TeamsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  var _clubs = [];
  get clubs => _clubs;
  Future loadValue() async {
    _clubs = await ApiService().getActiveSeasonClubs();
    return _clubs;
  }
}
```

In your future builder use `future: teamsProv.loadValue()`.
When you want to read the list, use `teamsProv.clubs`.

If you want to modify this list form outside your provider class, create another void function there, that takes the changes as parameters, and uses them to modify `_clubs` from outside the class.